# gopacket: DecodeLayers on an IP-in-IP Packet

Tags: go, gopacket

If I have data I'm putting through a `DecodingLayerParser` and some of that data could have IP Protocol 4 (IP-in-IP) packets included, how would I get it to capture BOTH IPv4 headers in the packet? I can only seem to get it to capture one of them.

```
type Decoder struct {
    eth   layers.Ethernet
    ip4   layers.IPv4
    ipip4 layers.IPv4
    ip6   layers.IPv6
    icmp4 layers.ICMPv4
    icmp6 layers.ICMPv6
    tcp   layers.TCP
    udp   layers.UDP
    //sip      layers.SIP
    //dns      layers.DNS
    //ntp      layers.NTP
    pay      gopacket.Payload
    parser   *gopacket.DecodingLayerParser
    types    []gopacket.LayerType
    unknowns map[string]uint
}

// NewDecoder allocates and initialises a new Decoder.
func NewDecoder() *Decoder {
    d := new(Decoder)
    d.parser = gopacket.NewDecodingLayerParser(layers.LayerTypeEthernet,
        &d.eth, &d.ip4, &d.ipip4, &d.ip6, &d.icmp4, &d.icmp6, &d.tcp, &d.udp, &d.pay)
    //&d.sip, &d.dns, &d.ntp, &d.pay)
    d.types = make([]gopacket.LayerType, 10, 10)
    d.parser.IgnoreUnsupported = true
    d.unknowns = make(map[string]uint)
    return d
}
```

How may I modify this in order to do this when `DecodeLayers` is called from the parser? It only seems to store the second IPv4 header's information in `ipip4`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Why it does not work

The interface `DecodingLayerContainer` is designed to index DecodingLayer by its LayerType (See [Decoder(LayerType) (DecodingLayer, bool)](https://github.com/google/gopacket/blob/32ee38206866f44a74a6033ec26aeeb474506804/parser.go#L63)). Since `ip4` and `ipip4` have the same LayerType (`layers.LayerTypeIPv4`), the latter will overwrite the former in the container. And every time `DecodingLayerParser` gets a decoder from the container for `layers.LayerTypeIPv4`, it gets `ipip4`. So the state of `ipip4` will be changed again and again.

#### A workaround

A workaround is to give `ip4` and `ipip4` different `LayerType`. And make `ip4` choose `ipip4` as its next decoder when the packet is an IP in IP packet. Here comes the demo:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io"

    "github.com/google/gopacket"
    "github.com/google/gopacket/layers"
    "github.com/google/gopacket/pcap"
)

// 0-999 are reserved for the gopacket library. Numbers 1000-1999 should be
// used for common application-specific types.
var LayerTypeIPv4Inner = gopacket.RegisterLayerType(1000, gopacket.LayerTypeMetadata{Name: "IP_in_IP", Decoder: nil})

// IPv4Outer is like layers.IPv4 but it recognizes IP in IP and will choose
// its next decoder accordingly.
type IPv4Outer struct {
    layers.IPv4
}

// NextLayerType overrides (*layers.IPv4).NextLayerType to recognize IP in IP.
func (i *IPv4Outer) NextLayerType() gopacket.LayerType {
    if i.Flags&layers.IPv4MoreFragments != 0 || i.FragOffset != 0 {
        return gopacket.LayerTypeFragment
    }
    // This is an IP in IP packet.
    // See https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc2003#section-3.1
    if i.Protocol == 4 {
        return LayerTypeIPv4Inner
    }
    return i.Protocol.LayerType()
}

// IPv4Inner is like layers.IPv4 except that its type is LayerTypeIPv4Inner.
// gopacket.DecodingLayerParser finds next decoder based on this type.
type IPv4Inner struct {
    layers.IPv4
}

// CanDecode overrides (*layers.IPv4).CanDecode to choose a type other than
// layers.LayerTypeIPv4.
func (i *IPv4Inner) CanDecode() gopacket.LayerClass {
    return LayerTypeIPv4Inner
}

func main() {
    handle, err := pcap.OpenOffline("./IP_in_IP.cap")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    var (
        eth     layers.Ethernet
        ip4     IPv4Outer
        ipip4   IPv4Inner
        tcp     layers.TCP
        icmpv4  layers.ICMPv4
        payload gopacket.Payload
    )
    parser := gopacket.NewDecodingLayerParser(layers.LayerTypeEthernet, &eth, &ip4, &ipip4, &tcp, &icmpv4, &payload)
    decodedLayers := make([]gopacket.LayerType, 0, 10)
    for {
        data, _, err := handle.ZeroCopyReadPacketData()
        if err == io.EOF {
            fmt.Println("done")
            return
        }

        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }

        err = parser.DecodeLayers(data, &decodedLayers)
        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }

        for _, typ := range decodedLayers {
            if typ == layers.LayerTypeIPv4 {
                fmt.Printf("Ipv4: %s => %s\n", ip4.SrcIP, ip4.DstIP)
            } else if typ == LayerTypeIPv4Inner {
                fmt.Printf("IP in IP: %s => %s\n", ipip4.SrcIP, ipip4.DstIP)
            }
        }

        fmt.Printf("%v\n\n", decodedLayers)
    }
}
```

I have tested with https://packetlife.net/media/captures/IP_in_IP.cap and [test_ethernet.pcap in gopacket](https://github.com/google/gopacket/blob/b42c052c5272831e5d93ddd6b5a261a78e753e3e/pcap/test_ethernet.pcap). The output looks like this:

```
Ipv4: 10.0.0.1 => 10.0.0.2
IP in IP: 1.1.1.1 => 2.2.2.2
[Ethernet IPv4 IP_in_IP ICMPv4 Payload]

Ipv4: 10.0.0.2 => 10.0.0.1
IP in IP: 2.2.2.2 => 1.1.1.1
[Ethernet IPv4 IP_in_IP ICMPv4 Payload]

Ipv4: 10.1.1.2 => 10.1.1.1
[Ethernet IPv4 TCP]

Ipv4: 10.1.1.1 => 10.1.1.2
[Ethernet IPv4 TCP]
```

#### Notes

1. `DecodingLayerParser` is faster, but it is also more rigid. while `PacketSource` is slower, it will handle any known type of packet safely and easily. (I'm sure you already know this).
2. This is only a workaround. I'm not sure if this is a best practice.
3. The purpose of the demo is to illustrate an idea to workaround such kind of issue. It does not work for other cases that a packet has multiple IPv4 headers. For example, it can not parse this file correctly: https://packetlife.net/media/captures/GRE.cap. We know that `DecodingLayerParser` is rigid and we have to handle other corner cases ourself.